# Routing not working when creating ui5 application using ui5-webcomponents-react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sap-business-technology-platform, ui5-webcomponents

I am creating one react app based **ui5-webcomponents-react**, and deploying it to the **SAP BTP**. Each time the app is directly loading the **index.html**. I am not sure how to use the **react-router** in this app.

***Files***

***approuter*** **->** ***xs-app.json***

```
{
 "welcomeFile": "todoapp/"
}
```

***public*** **->** ***xs-app.json***

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "index.html",
  "authenticationMethod": "route",
  "logout": {
     "logoutEndpoint": "/do/logout"
   },
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "^(.*)$",
      "target": "$1",
      "service": "html5-apps-repo-rt",
      "authenticationType": "xsuaa"
    }
   ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
<ThemeProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
</ThemeProvider>
);
```

I have added the routes in the **App.js**

```
 /*Removed unnecessary code for clarity*/
 return(
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Worklist/>}/>
        <Route path="/detail" element={<Detail/>}/>
    </Routes>
 )
```

**Worklist.js**

```
 /*Removed unnecessary code for clarity*/
 return(
    <div>Worklist</div>
 )
```

The initial div element (*Worklist component*) is not showing on the index.html page.
And I have doubts about how to navigate to another page, and how the URL might look.

Comment: Are you rendering a router in the app somewhere? Are there any errors in the terminal or console?

Comment: The route is added only in the App.js

Comment: There needs to be a router rendered somewhere in the app so the `Routes` and `Route` components have a routing context available to them. Please edit the post to include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. See [mcve]. Please do try to also clarify in more detail what exactly the issue is, what isn't working, any errors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this problem I used *basename* inside *BrowserRouter*, so the urls will be *xxxx/index.html* or *xxxx/index.html/foobar*.
I used this solution cause if you change ***"welcomeFile": "index.html"*** to ***"welcomeFile": ""*** it doesn't recognize the app.
It's probably not the prettiest solution but it's certainly the fastest and most effective for a React app inside SAP environment.
So, to use an easy router (React-Router v6), the code will be like this:

```js
// example_complete_url = https://xxx.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/my-sap-deployed-app-url/index.html
const base_url = "/my-sap-deployed-app-url/index.html";

<BrowserRouter basename={base_url}>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/foobar" element={<Foobar />} />
        <Route path="/404" element={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If I find other ways to do it I'll edit my answer.

---

EDIT WITH SOLUTION that works with refresh or path changes:
I figure out how to manage this issue by using hashRouter from ReactRouter6. This method doesn't require using a basename like with the browserRouter. Here it is an easy example:

```js
import { createHashRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createHashRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <PageHome />, },
  { path: "/page2", element: <Page2 />, },
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).